# Is there an easy way to refactor or compile Fortran code for row major storage?

Tags: fortran, memory-optimization, column-major-order

I have some very old, legacy Fortran code that I am trying to speed up.  A major performance issue, is that it utilizes very many, very large 3-D arrays stored as (Y,Z,X) and individual (Z,X) layers have to communicated over a network.

This requires me to traverse the arrays and buffer them before sending since Fortran uses column major format.  Is there an easy way, like a compiler flag or a refactoring tool, to make it so my (Z,X) layers sit in contiguous memory or to swap Fortran to row-major array order?

Comment: That `x(2,1)` rather than `x(1,2)` is the element after `x(1,1)` is a rather fundamental part of Fortran.

Comment: @francescalus I'm aware, and if I had the luxury of writing my code from scratch instead of inheriting 50,000 lines of thirty-year-old code I would have had the indices in the right order from the start.  I'm kinda stuck with what I've got right now though.  SOMEONE must have had to find an elegant way to deal with this before...

Comment: *SOMEONE must have had to find an elegant way to deal with this before*  Well, perhaps.  But also possible - a previous person in the same situation as you, perhaps 10 years ago or so, asked the code the same question and ran some tests to investigate the relative costs (in performance) of reshaping all the arrays to make communications speedier, and of computation on the re-ordered and un-re-ordered arrays and determined that the current design hit an acceptable trade-off.  That may no longer be true, the relative speeds of communication v computation has changed a lot ...

Comment: ... in the last decade.  But it might be worth your while testing your hypothesis before committing to a major refactoring.  And give up on your hope that some magic compiler flag is going to do that for you.  I've been programming in Fortran since the 70s and I've never come across a compiler that could do anything like that.

Comment: On the other hand in ancient history when the earth was young there have been scripts that would provide a source to source mapping with reordered indices. A good 1 minute googling shows up nothing, but they might still be hiding on some long forgotten web page. But I'm talking when F77 was king so even if you find one it might not cope with modern syntax.

Comment: Does the intrinsic TRANSPOSE provide any assistance for you? I.e. You could send them out and TRANSPOSE on the receiving side, (which might be faster as they would be scattered across more processing nodes...) I almost always have the TRANSPOSE sit on the F90 side, but you can also wrap that F90 function and link it with any C code using ISO_C_BINDING... if you wanted it to be done in the C-side.

Comment: @Holmz I didn't want to get into the weeds going over this because I don't feel I need help with the communication side of things, but this is actually MPI code.  I have tested both using spanned data types and manually copying the data into a buffer, and from my testing both methods are significantly slower than having the data in the right arrangement to begin with.

Comment: Yeah @Frank I mean send the data out to the nodes, then on the distributed side which receives the work to do... TRANSPOSE (to get it column major), do the work, then TRANSPOSE to put the data back how you store it in row major back how the MPI sender expects it. (Maybe that would be worth a try?)

Comment: @Holmz I don't know how that's substantively different than copying the data into a buffer with I loop as I'm doing, but I suppose it's worth a shot

Comment: @Frank I am interested as to what's you find. I believe it could be potentially better if the far nodes are many... as it shoves that work out.